# Pandas - dropping rows with missing data not working using .isnull(), notnull(), dropna()

Tags: python, pandas

This is really weird. I have tried several ways of dropping rows with missing data from a pandas dataframe, but none of them seem to work.
This is the code (I just uncomment one of the methods used - but these are the three that I used in different modifications - this is the latest):

```
import pandas as pd
Test = pd.DataFrame({'A':[1,2,3,4,5],'B':[1,2,'NaN',4,5],'C':[1,2,3,'NaT',5]})
print(Test)
#Test = Test.ix[Test.C.notnull()]
#Test = Test.dropna()
Test = Test[~Test[Test.columns.values].isnull()]
print "And now"
print(Test)
```

But in all cases, all I get is this:

```
   A    B    C
0  1    1    1
1  2    2    2
2  3  NaN    3
3  4    4  NaT
4  5    5    5
And now
   A    B    C
0  1    1    1
1  2    2    2
2  3  NaN    3
3  4    4  NaT
4  5    5    5
```

Is there any mistake that I am making? or what is the problem? Ideally, I would like to get this:

```
   A    B    C
0  1    1    1
1  2    2    2
4  5    5    5
```

Comment: Do you actually have the strings `NaN` and `NaT` instead of `np.nan` and `np.datetime64('NaN')` - as `.dropna()` will work correctly with the later...

Comment: the string or np.nan didn't make any difference :(

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Your example DF has `NaN` and `NaT` as strings which `.dropna`, `.notnull` and co. won't consider falsey, so given your example you can use...

```
df[~df.isin(['NaN', 'NaT']).any(axis=1)]
```

Which gives you:

```
   A  B  C
0  1  1  1
1  2  2  2
4  5  5  5
```

If you had a DF such as (note of the use of `np.nan` and `np.datetime64('NaT')` instead of strings:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'A':[1,2,3,4,5],'B':[1,2,np.nan,4,5],'C':[1,2,3,np.datetime64('NaT'),5]})
```

Then running `df.dropna()` which give you:

```
   A    B  C
0  1  1.0  1
1  2  2.0  2
4  5  5.0  5
```

Note that column `B` is now a `float` instead of an integer as that's required to store `NaN` values.

Answer (score 15):

Try this on orig data:

```
Test.replace(["NaN", 'NaT'], np.nan, inplace = True)
Test = Test.dropna()
Test
```

Or Modify data and do this

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np 

Test = pd.DataFrame({'A':[1,2,3,4,5],'B':[1,2,np.nan,4,5],'C':[1,2,3,pd.NaT,5]})
print(Test)
Test = Test.dropna()
print(Test)



   A    B  C
0  1  1.0  1
1  2  2.0  2
4  5  5.0  5
```

Comment: I used with Test.replace([''], np.nan, inplace = True) ,ty