# Dropping nan string-columns in panda dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

[image: df example]

I would like to drop all "nan" columns (like the first one on the image) as it doesn't contain any information. I tried this using

```
df.dropna(how='all', axis=1, inplace=True)
```

which unfortunately had no effect. I am afraid that this might be the case because I had to convert my df into a string using

```
df = df.applymap(str)
```

This [Thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39339935/pandas-dropping-rows-with-missing-data-not-working-using-isnull-notnull) suggests that dropna won't work in such a case, which makes sense to me.
I tried to loop over the columns using:

```
for i in range(len(list(df))):
    if df.iloc[:,i].str.contains('nan').all():
        df.drop(columns=i,axis=1, inplace=True)
```

which doesn't seem to work. Any help how to drop those columns (and rows as that also doesn't work) is much appreciated

Comment: Try `df.replace('nan', np.nan).dropna(how='all', axis=1, inplace=True)`

Comment: This work just fine, thanks a lot!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

IIUC, try:

```
df.replace('nan', np.nan).dropna(how='all', axis=1, inplace=True)
```

This will replace those string 'nan' with np.nan allowing `dropna` to function as expected.